# В каких случаях стоит выполнять проверку интернет соединения?

Tags: java, android

Пишу REST API приложение и при каждом запросе к серверу, сперва проверяю на наличие интернет соединения, и только в случае положительного результата, посылаю запрос на сервер.

Правильно ли я делаю?  Или в каких случаях стоит выполнять проверку?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ну когда правильно проверять наличие интернет соединения вопрос в общем случае довольно спорный. У нас в компании в основном если и проверяем наличие соединения, то только при запуске приложения что бы уведомить пользователя что без интернета приложение работать не сможет. Если же интернет обрывается после открытия приложеньки, то просто обрабатываем ошибки выполнения запросов и выводим пользователю соответствующие уведомления или вместо очередного экрана приложеньки показываем заглушку с описанием что случилось.

Проверять при каждом запросе в любом случае бессмысленно ибо интернет может пропасть после проверки, но до окончания выполнения запроса. Да и то что проверка прошла как правило не гарантирует что интернет действительно есть, может соединение с каким нить гуглом и проходит, а до вашего REST сервера не достучаться.

Comment: Замечательный ответ! Спасибо!